# Unity - Cant access script from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

I cant access a script from my "GameManager" Script.

Maybe they dont know each other, because they are in different folders?

But if I try to move the scripts from one folder to another subfolder - all references die!

It would be really hard to configure all scripts again from the scratch.

Heres is where my GameManager is:

[image: GameManager-Directory]

Here is where my Gun_Controller_ is:

[image: Gun_Controller_ - Directory]

Heres the error:

[image]

How can i solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either add reference to that script in editor, or make script static if you can

Comment: What do you mean by "add reference to that script"?

Comment: Create a public instance in one class and in editor assign othe class to it

Comment: It didnt work out for me.

Comment: how can I make a script static?

Comment: There is not enough information about your scripts, what are you trying and so on.

Comment: Iam working on a "boost" in my GameManager.

Comment: If my boost ist 100% i want to change something in my "Gun_Controller"

Comment: Is there any solution to move the scripts without configuring all references?

Comment: Please learn how to explain a problem. Are you getting some error or something? Compile or run-time error? A screenshot of the scripts are placed if this is a compile-time error?

Comment: ok im sry. I know how to access other scripts from a script - worked fine for me in other scripts. But in my GameManager it is not possibile to even write it without an error. It says that "Type or namespace not found"... Means: My GameManager does not know about a script with the name "Gun_Controller_". I think its because of that they are in different folders. But moving them didtn work out for me

Comment: This is the information that should be in your question. 1.The script including the name and namespace. 2. A screenshot of where both scripts are. 3.How and where you are trying to access it. 4. The error you mentioned above.  Without those, look at the comments under the question. They are asking for more information instead of trying to answer your question......

Comment: ok, im going to add screenshots

Comment: Please copy/paste your code here instead of posting screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script is placed in the *"Standard Assets"* folder, you **can't** access scripts from other folders such as the *"Assets"* folder from that script that is placed in the *"Standard Assets"* folder.

Your `GameManager` script is placed in the *"Standard Assets"* folder. The `Gun_Controller_` script you are trying to access is placed in the *"Assets"* folder.

You have two options:

**1**.Move the `GameManager` script to the *"Assets"* folder

**2**.Move the `Gun_Controller_` script to the *"Standard Assets"* folder.

Comment: Thank You - I will try it. Bit it seems legit ;)

Comment: Now I get a compiler Error when i move the GameManager to the "Assets" Folder..

Comment: If i move the file, all the references of the other sripts die too :/ Is there any workaraound?

Comment: This question is about not being able to access your script. This answers that. Please create a new question for your other issues such as lost of references in the Editor. *"Now I get a compiler"* You were already getting a compile error in your question which is why I put this answer. This should fix that error. If you have another error, say what it is. Add EDIT to your question and add your new error under there.

Comment: Here is the link:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737061/unity-move-script-files-to-other-directory-without-reference-loss