# Unity - Move Script-Files to other directory without reference loss

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, directory

I have to move my GameManager-Script to a higher directory, due to accessability from another script.

But if I try to move the script from one folder to another directory - all references die! And I mean like - all references from all scripts.

It would be really hard to configure all scripts again from the scratch. Its like starting from the beginning.

Here is the GameManagement-Directory (Assets->Standard Assets):

[image]

Here is the the Directory, where I have to move the "GameManagement" to (Assets):

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to move scripts without reference loss.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "all references die"?

Comment: All the references like script relations to GameObjects cannot be found...

Comment: All my inputs like Audio Files and Animation "Links" to these GameObjects are unlinked

Comment: And the worst thing is that the IDE didnt compile my project

Comment: Good news is: If I move the files back to their originally directory - everything works fine again.. But I need access to that script...

Comment: Something like this doesn't exist yet. You will need to write a plugin for this. The plugin will scan your project and get path and references of all scripts. When you move them, it will detect the new script, check if it exists in the memory then copy all the references back.

Comment: hmm ok... Do you think if I move scripts to another folder, all the references should be fine? (usaually)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok guys I know what the problem was.

If you move files in Unity, make sure that you do that in the Explorer - NOT in the IDE.

Because you have to move the metadata-file with the script as well.

That worked for me.